# Storing certain value in Widget build / Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've a question:

In my `Widget build(BuildContext context)`, I want to store a certain value,

```dart
final userName = book.owner
```

(book is the reference to the certain value from Firestore)

But it's done not in the right way to my lack of knowledge. I'd appreciate if someone could guide through that.

Thank you in advance!

**Snippet of my code**

```
class BookView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Book book;
  BookView({Key key, @required this.book}) : super(key: key);

  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = new DatabaseMethods();
  var userName;
  @override
  _BookViewState createState() => _BookViewState(book);
}

class _BookViewState extends State<BookView> {
  Book book;
  _BookViewState(this.book);
  String userName;
  @override
  void initState() {
    userName = book.owner;

    super.initState();
  }

  // final Book book;
  createChatroomAndStartConversation({var userName}) {
    if (userName != Constants.myName) {
      String roomId = getChatRoomId(userName, Constants.myName);

      List<String> users = [userName, Constants.myName];
      Map<String, dynamic> chatRoomMap = {
        "Users": users,
        "roomId": roomId,
      };

      DatabaseMethods().createChatRoom(roomId, chatRoomMap);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ConversationScreen(roomId, userName)),
      );
    } else {
      print("You cannot send msg to your self");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //widget.book;
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
    ...
                            FlatButton(
                              child: Text(
                                "Get contact with",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              onPressed: () {
                                createChatroomAndStartConversation(
                                    userName: userName);
 ...
}
```

**Snippet of Value not in range: 1**

```
getChatRoomId(String a, String b) {
  if (a.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0) > b.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0)) {
    return "$b\_$a";
  } else {
    return "$a\_$b";
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How are you currently doing it , and why do you consider it not the right way?

Comment: Well on this point i get error : ' Expected to find ')' ' , but i doesn't make any sense. If you need i can add code snippet as well @croxx5f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good practice to store any data in `build()` method, because this method is invoked too many times to do the such kind of move. Consider using `StatefulWidget` to store any state you have in the widget, **for the very beginning**. When you use this widget, you can define this all in such way:

```
class YourWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _YourWidgetState createState() => _YourWidgetState();
}

class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> {
  String userName;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    userName = book.owner;
    
    super.initState()
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Text(userName),);
  }
}
```

Here, in `initState()` you can retrieve value from book and set it to `userName`. But for more complex and bigger applications, **consider using StateManagement solutions** and some kind of architectural patterns i.e. Riverpod, Provider, MobX, BLoC.. Because changing the state via `setState()` method will cause rebuilding whole child widget tree, which could freeze whole UI in complex app.

**UPD to 'Snippet of my code':**

According to your code, if you are using a 'book' from Widget, not its state - use `widget.book`, in such way you have access to widget members, because of this you don't need a constructor of state. So, due to these changes, your code might looks like:

```
class BookView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Book book;
  BookView({Key key, @required this.book}) : super(key: key);

  // You DON'T need this here, because you are retrieving these methods 
  // inside your state via DatabaseMethods constructor
  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = DatabaseMethods();
  
  @override
  _BookViewState createState() => _BookViewState(book);
}

class _BookViewState extends State<BookView> {
  String userName;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // Using widget.book to retrieve Book object from state's widget
    userName = widget.book.owner;

    super.initState();
  }

  createChatroomAndStartConversation({var userName}) {
    if (userName != Constants.myName) {
      String roomId = getChatRoomId(userName, Constants.myName);
      
      // Also, it's just a recommendation, try to omit local variables types
      // because they are already known with List type (String). Also, this 
      // all is about chatRoomMap
      var users = <String>[userName, Constants.myName];
      final chatRoomMap = <String, dynamic>{
        "Users": users,
        "roomId": roomId,
      };

      DatabaseMethods().createChatRoom(roomId, chatRoomMap);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ConversationScreen(roomId, userName)),
        );
      } else {
        print("You cannot send msg to your self");
    }
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // your widgets here
  }
}
```

**UPD 2:**

Second trouble and issue with 'Snippet of Value not in range: 1'. I could to reproduce it with given value of '*a*' as empty string. So, your function invocation is like `getChatRoomId('', 'user123')`, because of empty '*userName*', substring function can't take values from range [0, 1), so exception is raised.

Comment: Ok i understand, but i have an issue now with 'book' reference, as it was working normally on the stateless widget( that's why i have chosen it because of simplicity, but i understand that it's not very good ), if you need i can add snippet of the code @mrfox

Comment: Yes, please. You could update your question with some additional code. @chorche

Comment: I have add it @mrfox

Comment: @Chorche , I've updated my answer about your code snippet and book reference issue, you can check it

Comment: If it will help, could you approve my answers please?:) @Chorche

Comment: Sorry for waiting, it was working on it very late. So I continued today and i found the mistake, i have some issues with constants. But all and all it works, very grateful @mrfox for your time U ROCK!

Comment: As you can see, everything could not be seen in question, but I'm very glad you've figured this out! @Chorche